# Which CRC is used to change key in Desfire Card

Tags: java, mifare

Which type of CRC is used to change key in Desfire Card?
Should the order of CRC bytes to reversed or not.
I cannot able to change the key of PICC applicaton.
Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRC16/32 and MAC/CMAC selection will depend on the Desfire card, CRC16 and MAC are for MF3ICD40 (backward compatibility). CRC16 is used if your DES key is 16 byte long but the first half and second half are the same. You can dig some info of whether resultant CRC should be reversed or not from this [link](http://www.repairfaq.org/filipg/LINK/F_crc_v3.html).